# Do Thingsboard support LwM2M multilpe instance object?

Tags: thingsboard, lwm2m, leshan

I have a sensor that uses multiple instances of the LwM2M Generic Sensor (3300) object. Sensor send a batch update of instances to Thingsboard LwM2M Server, but it doesn't show this report.

I test my sensor with the Leshan server and Leshan shows the list of instance batch update values which means the sensor is working properly.

should I configure Thingsboard to support lwM2M multiple instance objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for multiple instances objects, you have to tell Thingsboard instance ID at Device profiles->LwM2M Model->Add New Instance (Plus Buttom at end of sensor row)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZ5G.png)